# Rationalize denominator with cos in it

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

sqrt(cos a+1)/(1-cos a)

I did (not sure how to format the final answer but the numerator should be sqrt'd.
$$\sqrt{\frac{{\cos a +1}}{1-\cos a}}=\sqrt{\frac{{\cos a +1}}{1-\cos a}\frac{{\cos a +1}}{1+\cos a}}=\left|\frac{1+\cos a}{\sin a}\right|$$
Thanks to gimusi for formatting.

Is that correct?

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt{\frac{{\cos a +1}}{1-\cos a}}$?

Comment: Yes I meant that. Thanks

Comment: @AndrewLi It doesn't make the denominator more rational, but when I rationalize the denominator it was equal to 1-cos^2a which is equal to sina. I may be wrong which is why I am asking for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a correct way to simplify, indeed
$$\sqrt{\frac{{\cos a +1}}{1-\cos a}}=\sqrt{\frac{{\cos a +1}}{1-\cos a}\frac{{\cos a +1}}{1+\cos a}}=\left|\frac{1+\cos a}{\sin a}\right|$$

Note also that since for the existence of square root we need

$$\cos a\neq 1 \quad\land\quad \frac{{\cos a +1}}{1-\cos a}\ge0\implies -1\le\cos a<1$$

thus we can write

$$\sqrt{\frac{{\cos a +1}}{1-\cos a}}=\frac{1+\cos a}{|\sin a|}$$

Comment: This is exactly what I did, except my answer the numerator is sqrtd $$\sqrt{\frac{{\cos a +1}}{1-\cos a}}=\sqrt{\frac{{\cos a +1}}{1-\cos a}\frac{{\cos a +1}}{1+\cos a}}=\left|\frac{1+\cos a}{\sin a}\right|$$

Comment: @Bill indeed I noticed that it was a bit different as result but I wasn't sure about what you were looking for, try to write in Tex to help the work!

Comment: @RobertFrost Thanks for your ping but really I’ve decided to ignore this kind of bad behavior and enjoy the site following my  way to enjoy with it. Thanks again, Bye

Comment: Good on you... Your answers are very helpful.

Comment: @RobertFrost Thanks a lot for your kind appreciation, I’ll try to do my best!